# How can I put this label above the node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a signal flow graph with this tikz library. I am very new to tikz and have no idea how to move the caption above the node. The alpha is hidden under the arrow at the lower left node. I already tried `label=above:` but then it doesn't compile.

https://github.com/kitmonisit/signalflow

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={anchor=center}]
  \matrix (m) [minimum width=6in,
    row sep=10mm,
    column sep=10mm]
  {%
    % row 1
    \node[input] (in)
    {$x[n]$}; &
    \node[node] (tap)
    {}; &&&
    \node[adder] (adder)
    {}; &
    \node[output] (out)
    {$y[n]$}; \\
    % row 2
        &
        &
    \node[block] (delay)
    {$z^{-k}$}; &
    \node[multiplier] (factor)
    {$\alpha$}; &&
    \\
  };


  \path[r>] (in) -- (tap);
  \path[r>] (tap) -- (adder);
  \path[r>] (adder) -- (out);
  \path[r>] (tap) |- (delay);
  \path[r>] (delay) -- (factor);
  \path[r>] (factor) -| (adder);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: What label above what node?

Comment: The alpha that is hidden under the arrow in the lower right.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Had to surround it with

`{\nodepart{above}{$\alpha$}}; &&`

as described here

https://texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/

Now it looks like this

[image]